# Preloading images in meteor from url

Tags: javascript, caching, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am getting images from DDP in objects. I'm getting images when I call a method from other app (thru ddp) and I get objects where are image id and image URL for each image. Now they are all big images and it takes about 5sec to load each when I click to show next in my app. Now, I want to preload them all in client. To explain it little better, when I monitor img loading in Meteor tools for chrome, I can see when ceach image is loading (only when I show that image), but I want to all of them load when I get them from that other app thru ddp. How could I do this? Thanks

**Update: code && posible solution**

So, this is my code, I am getting images here and calling function that is cashing pictures, it workes in localhost and it is pritty nice solutin but when it is deploy i get this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://tasks-dev.microwork.io/imageQA' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://52.39.141.15:11011/simplentp/sync'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**Code:**

```
...

this.autorun(() => {
        const user = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId(), {fields: {'services.MicroworkOAuth2Server.accessToken': 1}})
        if (user && user.services && user.services.MicroworkOAuth2Server) {
            Meteor.call('getImagesForQA', user.services.MicroworkOAuth2Server.accessToken, 10, (error, images) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                } else {
                    console.log('Images recieved: ', images)
                    this.current.set(0)
                    this.images.set(images)
                    this.isLoading.set(false)

                    preload(images)

                    wheelzoom($('.open-image'))
                }
            })
        } else {
            this.isLoading.set(true)
        }
    })

...
```

**Localhost solution, but error on deployed**

```
preload = function preloadImages(srcs) {
if (!preloadImages.cache) {
    preloadImages.cache = [];
}
var img;
for (var i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = srcs[i].imageURL;
    console.log(img)
    preloadImages.cache.push(img);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have some small example code how you do that right now?

Comment: I'll update question